# filter: gradient and background: fixed

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

Code:

`body { background-attachment: fixed !important; filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Gradient(gradientType=0,startColorStr=#000000,endColorStr=#3d3c3c); }`

Gradient does not stay fixed in IE8 but scrolls into a plain white background. Gradients stay fixed in Firefox and Chrome and scroll with the page.

Is there any way to have it `fixed` in IE8 as well? I wasn't even aware this was an issue (can't find anything according to Google).

Edit: I created a test page with the code above (and quite a bit of Lorem Ipsum) and the background was fixed like it should be. So it must be something in my layout.

Comment: I have IE 8.0.6001.18702 and using your code, with scrolling content, the gradient stays fixed for me. I never see a white background.  Since the filter being used will ONLY work in IE, I don't think the method you use for Firefox and Chrome are relevant. Could you provide a fiddle that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: Relevant possibly not, but very annoying since the styles for Moz and Webkit work the way I want them to. http://jsfiddle.net/g83DW/ for the fiddle, but really I'm not sure what difference it is between the code I posted above and that. Though I will say that even the fiddle is a good example as the gradient runs from the top of the preview to the bottom, and scrolls instead of displaying the entire gradient in the 'window' and staying fixed.

Comment: Everything in my layout is either absolute or fixed positioned, would that cause an issue even if the body height is 100%?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like all you're missing is to set a height on the body.  Adding this style works for me in IE 8:

`html, body {height: 100%}`

So, using your style from your fiddle, it would look like this:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
body {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#000000, endColorstr=#ffffff);
}
```

And this is what the cross-browser version would look like:

```
html, body {height: 100%}
body {
    background-attachment: fixed !important;
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0, startColorstr=#000000, endColorstr=#ffffff);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(center top -90deg, #000000, #ffffff);
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 0% 100%, from(#000000), to(#ffffff));
}
```

Obviously, you could put the IE specific code elsewhere and load it conditionally, etc.

This tested fine in IE 8, Firefox 3.6, Chrome 9 & Safari 5 (Webkit) but does not work in Opera.  For Opera, SVG or actual background image?

Comment: `body` actually had its height set to 100% along with html elsewhere in the code. Sorry for not including it then, but I've been coding a lot in the past few days, mine and other people's. :) As I said above, it does seem to work in styles other than my main one. I'm not sure why this is, and I've taken apart my CSS trying to figure it out, but I have had literally no luck finding it. The funny thing is along the way I discovered that IE refuses to allow filters on elements with `display: none;` which are of course to be called in later using jQuery. Continued . . .

Comment: My eventual conclusion was that it simply refused to work, needing *something* to be wrong with itself, so I set the background colour to the bottom gradient and simply allowed the body background to scroll along with the content. For the `display: none;` problems, I used a transparent background image. I hated resorting to that (so damn much!) but if solving the problem another way, albeit less desirable, its not broken. Its just IE.

Comment: My code **does** produce the desired result. However, as you stated, the problem lies elsewhere in your CSS and without seeing it I don't know what else to suggest. The `display: none` problem IS a bummer, but it's IE; what else can you say?

Comment: I think it had something to do with the body not extending the full height of the page, honestly, but this was the same layout I was having the other problem with so eh. The userbase for this particular project is not the type to be using IE anyway, so the 'workaround' was much faster and convenient than disassembling my CSS that worked flawlessly in the browsers they would be using. As I said I hated to leave a bug in there, but with everything else working and that not looking 'ugly', I said screw it, it's IE, something's going to go not quite as expected, and left it to work 98% correctly.

Comment: For the record, I'm not sure why you had to declare that your code works. It obviously does. I'm going to mark your answer as the right one because, in most situations, it would be the right answer. It just happens that IE is hateful with this particular layout. ;)

Comment: I wasn't stating my code works so that you would mark it as correct. I was kind of thinking out loud: "example works so must be other CSS I cannot see". Point of reference, that's all. I would not feel comfortable with my answer being accepted because you were already using the code I suggested.